# How to use one XSLT template for different level elements?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XML document

```
<ren:RewardAct>
    <ren:RewardAttrList>
        <ren:RrewardAttr>
            <ren:AttrName>11111111111111</ren:AttrName>
            <ren:AttrValue>11111111111111</ren:AttrValue>
        </ren:RrewardAttr>
    </ren:RewardAttrList>
    <ren:RewardList>
        <ren:Reward>
            <ren:Credit>
                <ren:Division>11111111111111</ren:Division>
                <ren:Region>11111111111111</ren:Region>
            </ren:Credit>
            <ren:RewardAttrList>
                <ren:RewardAttr>
                    <ren:AttrName>11111111111111</ren:AttrName>
                    <ren:AttrValue>11111111111111</ren:AttrValue>
                </ren:RewardAttr>
            </ren:RewardAttrList>
 . . .
```

And I want something like this

```
  <RewDocSum>
    <RewDocSum_ITEM>
      <Value>1000.00</Value>
      <Name>string</Name>
    </RewDocSum_ITEM>
  </RewDocSum>
  <RewCategorOutlets>
    <RewCategorOutlets_ITEM>
      <GroupSum>
        <GroupSum_ITEM>
          <Value>1000.00</Value>
          <Name>string</Name>
        </GroupSum_ITEM>
      </GroupSum>
  . . .
```

For element `<ren:RewardAttrList>` and it's child elements I am trying to use template with parameters, so translations looks like

```
    <xsl:template match="//ren:RewardAct">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ren:RewardAttrList">
                <xslt:with-param name="listName" select="'RewDocSum'"/>
                <xslt:with-param name="itemName" select="'RewDocSum_ITEM'"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ren:RewardList"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ren:RewardList">
        <RewCategorOutlets>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ren:Reward"/>
        </RewCategorOutlets>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ren:Reward">
        <RewCategorOutlets_ITEM>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ren:RewardAttrList">
                <xslt:with-param name="listName" select="'GroupSum'"/>
                <xslt:with-param name="itemName" select="'GroupSum_ITEM'"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <Credits>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ren:Credit"/>
            </Credits>
        </RewCategorOutlets_ITEM>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ren:Credit">
        <Credits_ITEM>
    . . .
        </Credits_ITEM>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//ren:RewardAttrList">
        <xsl:param name="listName"/>
        <xsl:param name="itemName"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$listName}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ren:RrewardAttr">
                <xslt:with-param name="listItemName" select="$itemName"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//ren:RrewardAttr">
        <xsl:param name="listItemName"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$listItemName}">
            <Value>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ren:AttrValue/node()"/>
            </Value>
            <Name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ren:AttrName/node()"/>
            </Name>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

So, template for `<ren:RewardAttrList>` works for outer element, but doesn't work for inner.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks for wasting your time and best regards.

Comment: Please post a short, but complete example - see [mcve]. -- **Hint:** a template matching `ren:RewardAttrList` matches **all** elements named `ren:RewardAttrList` in the entire document. However, you must make to *apply templates* to all relevant nodes during the transformation process. Usually, this is done recursively - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model

Comment: Also note that for your first `ren:RewardAttrList` list, the child elements are `ren:RrewardAttr`, which you handle correctly in your XSLT, but the second one has child elements called `ren:RewardAttr`, which is not matched by the XSLT.

Comment: Thanks to @Tim C. My eyes tired and I just don't seen the difference between `ren:RrewardAttr` and `ren:RewardAttr`.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in different child element names:

```
ren:RrewardAttr
ren:RewardAttr
```

After correcting element names and XSD scheme, template with parameters works fine.

Thanks all, especially @Tim C